# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/contact.html

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I fails to connect my index.html page with contact.html page it shows this above error when i tried
Using the URLconf defined in Website.urls,

> Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/
>
> [name='home-page']
>
> Contact/
>
> The current path, contacts/contact.html, didn't match any of these.

This my contacts.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('Contact', views.contacts, name='contact-us')
]
```

my contacts.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def contacts(Request):
    return render(Request, 'contact.html')
```

my website.urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('Websiteapp.urls')),
    path('Contact/', include('contacts.urls'))
]
```

Comment: You have configured the contacts-view to appear at `/Contact/Contact`.

Answer (score 1):

The template should be with the full path starting from any of the `template` directories.

since the convention is `myappname/templates/myappname/`, we'll clip from after `templates`.

like this

```
def contacts(Request):
    return render(Request, 'myappname/contact.html/')
```

and the pattern should be all lower case, like this
`mywebsite.urls`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('Websiteapp.urls')),
    path('contact/', include('contacts.urls'))
]
```

`contacts.urls`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('contact', views.contacts, name='contact-us')
]
```

now access it from `contact/contact`

Answer (score 1):

Your URL patterns suggest you should access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Contact/Contact`.

Answer (score 0):

Try open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Contact/`
as you define **/Contact/** in your urls.py

Comment: SORRY NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0):

> Django [URL dispatcher doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters) is very clear

```
# In settings/urls/main.py
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('<username>/blog/', include('foo.urls.blog')),
]

# In foo/urls/blog.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blog.index),
    path('archive/', views.blog.archive),
]
```