# How will I connect my index.html to my views.py?

Tags: python, django

I tried doing this:
[image]

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'templates/index.html')
```

But my page says that TemplateDoesNotExist.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/contact.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60938227/page-not-found-404-request-methodget-request-urlhttp-127-0-0-18000-cont)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder 'justcolor' under templates directory and save index.html in it. change path to 'justcolor/index.html'. return render(request, 'justcolor/index.html')

Comment: `templates` better be a subdir of the app, not of the project. And I think the template path is case sensitive too, so it's `justColor/index.html`

Comment: I don't have an app for this project. This simply is the subdirectory for my project

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks. I was able to solve my own problem on my own. In fact, I posted the right answer for this question here. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured urls.py and views.py correctly.

This question is already answered here :[Django TemplateDoesNotExist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist)

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks. I was able to solve my own problem on my own. In fact, I posted the right answer for this question here. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `templates\justColor` subdirectory template inside your `justColor` folder and move `index.html` to there. Then as @Neeraj said you can change render call to  `render(request, 'justColor/index.html')`.

(Although you should read this part of the django tutorial which will help you more than any trial-and-error in this subject: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/)

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks. I was able to solve my own problem on my own. In fact, I posted the right answer for this question here. But thanks anyways.

Comment: @ZeddrixFabian you've probably changed the `DIRS` variable on `settings.py` to add the template directory right ? My answer was a secondary option when you enable apps on the settings file.